# (Excel) Formula to Sum numbers contained in a String (w/o using 'Evaluate')

Tags: excel-formula

I've searched the web but can't wrap my head around it.

- Problem: Individual cell containing string of one or more numbers in percent. If there are multiple numbers, they are separated by a linebreak CHAR(10). Example. cell A1 has this value:

  ```
   96%
    4%
    3%
  ```
- Wanted outcome: Sum up of the numbers irrespective of how many there are. In the above example, result should be 103%.
- Challenge: Must be done via a simple single-cell formula, macros (i.e. '=Evaluate') not possible

Here my formula so far:

```
=TEXT(IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))>0,
(SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",",""),CHAR(10),REPT(" ",100)),{1,100},100)))),
A1)
),"0.00%")
```

Where the part in questions is:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", ""),CHAR(10),REPT(" ",100)),{1,100},100))))
```

Which also contains a fail-safe in case a user adds a comma as a separator in addition to the linebreak.

The formula however will always only sum the first two numbers in the string, in this case 96% and 4%... I must admit I'm not comfortable with MID to understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<h><e>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),CHAR(10),"</e><e>")&"</e></h>","//e"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using at least Excel 2013, then this must be entered as an array formula (unless you have dynamic arrays)

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<h><e>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(10)),CHAR(10),"</e><e>")&"</e></h>","//e"))
```

Comment: Can't say anything other than "Thank you!" : )

Comment: Two things to add:
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<h><e>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),CHAR(10),"</e><e>")&"</e></h>","//e"))
This will correctly fail-safe the "," and avoids the need to declare the array via CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: +1 for SUMPRODUCT() - I'd be careful about eliminating the comma delimiter, though:
if the contents of A1 are e.g. 96%,4%CHAR(10)3%CHAR(10)15% then my formula would return 1.18 but using the formula where the comma delimiter is eliminated entirely would only return 0.18